# Insert 500 rows to MySQL from PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bulkinsert

`codes` table

```
id     code
--    ------
1     BB3CA4
2     2788BA
3     E3E3A5
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

PHP array of 500 semi-unique strings called `$codes` to be added to the `codes` table:

```
$codes = array( 'AC2BE4', 'BC61A2', '34CE5A', ... );
```

My PDO database connection object:

```
$dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass );
```

---

### Try 1

Put PDO insert execute within the PHP loop:

```
foreach( $codes as $code ){
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO codes ( code ) VALUES ( :code )");
    $stmt->bindParam( ':code', $code , PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I think this is not a good solution!

### Try 2

Second try was to construct a long SQL query by gluing 500 SQL queries and run it at once.

Comment: If this is necessary only one time, you can use first code.

Answer (score 3):

Prepared statements that do the same query but with different parameters don't have to be created multiple times, just once, so create the statement before the loop, then iterate, you bind the parameters and execute the query inside the loop.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO codes ( code ) VALUES ( :code )");
foreach( $codes as $code ){
  $stmt->bindParam( ':code', $code , PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

With `PDO` you could even slim the code down a little bit by setting the parameter/s in the execute call:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO codes ( code ) VALUES ( :code )');
foreach($codes as $code) {
  $stmt->execute(array('code' => $code));
}
```

Comment: are multiple executions more efficient than say, imploding multiple groups of brackets of values together, and running them all as a single query?

Comment: I'm not sure if its faster, but its safer, cause you get the extra protection from injections that prepared statements gives.  
And when it comes to 500 inserts, it won't really matter, its fast either way and easier to write with like above in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO codes ( code ) VALUES ";
 foreach($codes as $code){        
    $sql = $sql . "($code),"
 }
 $sql = rtrim($sql,",");
```

I think this is a simple way to insert 500 values at a time into database.